# Rails, Postgres 12, Query where pattern matches regex, and contains substring

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have a field in the database which contains strings that look like: `58XBF2022L1001390` I need to be able to query results which match the last letter(in this case 'L'), and match or resemble the last four digits.

The regular expression I've been using to find records which match the structure is: `\d{2}[A-Z]{3}\d{4}[A-Z]\d{7}`, So far I've tried using a scope to refine the results, but I'm not getting any results.  Here's my scope

```
def self.filter_by_shortcode(input)
  q = input
  starting = q.slice!(0)
  ending = q
  where("field ~* ?", "\d{2}[A-Z]{3}\d{4}/[#{starting}]/\d{3}[#{ending}]\g")
end
```

Here are some more example strings, and the substring that we would be looking for. Not every string stored in this database field matches this format, so we would need to be able to first match the string using the regex provided, then search by substring.

- 36GOD8837G6154231

  - G4231
- 13WLF8997V2119371

  - V9371
- 78FCY5027V4561374

  - V1374
- 06RNW7194P2075353

  - P5353
- 57RQN0368Y9090704

  - Y0704

edit: added some more examples as well as substrings that we would need to search by.

Comment: Add some example data. What are some rows in your database, what is `input`, what is the result you're getting, which rows are you expecting to match?

Comment: ok, I added some more example strings as well as the input I'd like to use to filter the results.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know Rails, but the SQL for what you want is relative simple. Since your string if fixed format, once that format is validated, simple concatenation of sub-strings gives your desired result.

```
with base(target, goal) as 
     ( values ('36GOD8837G6154231', 'G4231')
            , ('13WLF8997V2119371', 'V9371')
            , ('78FCY5027V4561374', 'V1374')
            , ('06RNW7194P2075353', 'P5353')
            , ('57RQN0368Y9090704', 'Y0704')
      )
select  substr(target,10,1) || substr(target,14,4) target, goal 
  from base 
 where target ~ '^\d{2}[A-Z]{3}\d{4}[A-Z]\d{7}$';
```